# Not to alter my hard drives data

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I currently have i windows 7 machine that has 4 internal hard drives ,
their sizes are not the same so i could spot and manage to difference them in the partitioning process:
I have 2 hard drives of 2 TB each full of date , a smaller one of 300 and the main drive on wich the windows file system are installed,900 GB `C:\`.

I want to install ubuntu on C and in the process not damage/Delete/alter my files on the other drives , i think they wil pop out something like :sda;sdb;sdc;sdd or something .

What must i do and what must i not do to avoid any trouble , i think i must partitionate the drive on which windows is currently installed to create files like /home /root swap etc ? ! .
 My main concern is in the process ubuntu don't delete the files on the other drives ,i alreaddy backed up everything i have on the C: drive, and the other question is will ubuntu be able after if everything went succesufuly and the other drives are intact , will ubuntu be able to read the drives and the files , and i could acces them easly without troubles . What measures should i take to avoid unpleasent situations like messing my files .
I want to install ubuntu as my only and primary os . Really beginner here,  hope i have a reasonable idea of what i am talking about..

Comment: This needs to be worked on to be readable, it's pretty hard to read and see what's being asked...

Comment: The easiest way to find out if you can read your current files: Create a live USB stick, boot it and test it. It's hard to give you advise concering your harddrives. Ubuntu will allow you to shrink partitions and if you are careful you won't delete anything. See this question: http://askubuntu.com/q/414005/75166 If you are still unsure about installing it, maybe you can ask some help from a local hackerspace? I'm sure they would love to give you a helping hand. You can locate one in your area here: http://hackerspaces.org/wiki/List_of_hackerspaces

Answer (score 0):

it may be a good idea to backup files from the win partition on a different drive before you start - if you are looking to shrink drives down before installing over windows partition as mike said a tip would be to use the micro$oft windows native drive shrinker as to avoid errors between *ix and win formatting.   Using the distro you want in live you should be able to identify what partition win core os is installed on (sda,sdb.. etc...) and when installing use that drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose the correct drive on setup, everything will be fine.

Ubuntu is able to read all common file systems, so you will be able to access your other hard drives natively with Ubuntu.

If you want to remove Windows entirely, just format the whole hard drive (The one with the right size) to ext4 or btrfs during setup. Leave some place for a swap partition if desired (at least the size of your RAM to enable hibernation etc.) and mark that partition/empty space as swap. Ubuntu will do the rest for you (unless you used the nice and easy automatic partition setup, in which case Ubuntu will do ALL partitioning for you).

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat hard to read, but if I get it right, your main point is to make it really, really save to not damage the data on the other disks?

There is no reason the Ubuntu setup should cause harm to the data on the other disks, of course; 
But you say partitioning under Linux is completely new to you,
and you will handle all your important data at once.

Then, it may still be a good idea to take some extra care - distraction and confusion does happen, and the difference between the right and the wrong disk is not much - like `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb`.

You could disconnect the extra harddrives.
They would not be accessible during the critical stuff like partitioning, it's just save.

You would not set up mountpoints for them in that stage - but after reconnecting the disks, you can use the disk setup tools again, but take care to not use any dangerous operations - if you do not define a partition to format, you can not hit the wrong disk with formating.

Reminds me of an old insight from the network world:
There's only one way to make it "really, really" save:
Use an air gap.

(There seem to be a few side-questions in the text - please post them as separate, concise questions.)